# Ruby on rails access to model information to an another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, mongoid

I have my first model `Contact` with the field `:email` and I need this same field `:email` in my model `Customer` with the value of the field `:email` which is in my model `Contact`.

I use mongoID for ORM so here's my first model Contact

```
class Contact
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  embedded_in :customer
  embedded_in :employee
  embedded_in :restaurant

  field :city
  field :street
  field :zip_code
  field :country
  field :phone_number
  field :email
```

and my second model Customer

```
class Customer
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  embeds_one :contact

  devise :database_authenticatable, :lockable, :recoverable,
         :rememberable, :registerable, :trackable, :timeoutable, :validatable,
         :token_authenticatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  field :first_name
  field :last_name
  field :password
  field :gender
  field :encrypted_password
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using activesupport, then delegate should do the job.

In customer.rb

```
delegate :email, :to => :contact
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just write your own setter/getter

```
class Customer
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_one :contact

  def email
    contact.email
  end

  def email=(string)
    contact.update_attributes(:email => string)
  end
end
```